# Problem with implementing drf_yasg (swagger) into django (AssertionError ModelSerializer)

Tags: python, django, swagger, drf-yasg

For couple of days im trying to implement drf_yasg into Django==3.1.3. Im always follow the instructions written here -> [https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#usage) (installation, urls).
Howerever, once im visiting swagger url definied in urls on my local machine error always occured ->:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApWXl.jpg)

and the console prints:

```
AssertionError: ("Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or 
the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit 
fields = '__all__' to the UserTokenSerializer serializer.",)
```

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: The error is fairly explicit: add a `fields` attribute to `UserTokenSerializer`

Comment: deffinetely, but how to fix it? I havent overrided UserTokenSerializer at all, its default as it was in rest_framework

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback? Which version of rest_framework do you have installed? There is no `UserTokenSerializer` included in rest_framework

Comment: I have installed :
djangorestframework==3.12.1,drf-yasg==1.20.0. here is a trace screenshot -> http://mign.pl/trace.jpg

Comment: where does UserTokenSerializer  come from, this is not default drf class whatsoever, look into import statement

Comment: indeed, but i havent imported this into my project, at the trace its visible it consist serializers.py located in python3.8 libraries -> http://mign.pl/trace.jpg

Comment: You're going to have to search your dependencies for this class if it does not exist in your code. Are you using any packages that may have some rest_framework integration?

Comment: You have to find where UserTokenSerializer comes from, it might come from your source and might come from another package, also you understanding of traceback and how objects/inheritance works  is flawed.